# Alterar mais de um valor na mesma coluna com um UPDATE

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Estou com a seguinte dúvida..

Possuo a tabela de exemplo - **resposta** no seguinte formato

```
*------------*--------------*
|resposta_id | INT          |  
|pergunta_id | INT          |   
|resposta    | VARCHAR(45)  |
*------------*--------------*
```

Com os seguinte registros:

```
resposta_id  pergunta_id   resposta
    1             1          ww
    2             1          ww
    3             2          xx
    4             2          xx
    5             3          xx
    6             3          xx
    7             3          xx
```

> Estou querendo fazer um **UPDATE** para alterar o campo de *resposta*
>   de acordo com o valor presente no campo *pergunta_id*.

Tentei assim:

```
UPDATE sch_Pessoal.resposta 
    set resposta = CASE resposta 
        WHEN pergunta_id = 1 THEN 'aaa'
        WHEN pergunta_id = 2 THEN 'bbb'
        WHEN pergunta_id = 3 THEN 'ccc'
    END
```

Porém o resultado é o seguinte;

```
resposta_id  pergunta_id   resposta
    1             1          bbb
    2             1          bbb
    3             2          aaa
    4             2          aaa
    5             3          aaa
    6             3          aaa
    7             3          aaa
```

Alguem pode auxiliar?

SQL Fiddle da estrutura:

[SQl Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5242/1/0)

Comment: Só uma dúvida. Não seria "WHEN resposta_id" ao invés de "WHEN pergunta_id"

Comment: Não Fabricio, nesse caso eu queria modificar o campo resposta, se baseando no campo 'pergunta_id' mesmo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foi somente um pequeno engano na sintaxe do `CASE`.

O correto seria:

```
UPDATE RESPOSTA 
    SET resposta = CASE  
            WHEN pergunta_id = 1 THEN 'aaa'
            WHEN pergunta_id = 2 THEN 'bbb'
            WHEN pergunta_id = 3 THEN 'ccc'
        END
```

[**Isso está funcionando da maneira que você deseja, veja no SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35f4bb/1)

Isso parece ter sido um efeito colateral pelo SGBD ter entendido O `resposta` entre o `CASE` e o `WHEN` como uma expressão.

Comment: Excelente Diego, falha minha mesmo rs. Muito obrigado!